# What is a "royal language"?

Tags: malchut-royalty, language, tosfot, masecheth-avodah-zarah

In explaining the gemara ([Avoda Zarah 10a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=10&format=pdf)) and Rashi, Tosfos write (sv שאין להם לא כתב ולא לשון):

> לכך פירש ר"י כתב לשון חשוב שהמלכים משתמשין בו כעין חכמת יונית....לשון
>   מלכות קאמר‏
>
> ....Therefore, the ר"י explained that the words "כתב ולשון" means a
>   language that the royalty would use, similar to חכמת יונית....that gemara ([Megilah 10b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=10b&format=pdf)) is also discussing a "royal language."

**What is a "royal language"? What characteristics would give a language "royal" status?** Must it be spoken by kings only? If plebeians also speak the language, does it lose "royal" status?

I'd like to know what Rishonim and Acharonim have to say on this, in particular.

Comment: I really found this gemara through a friend, who I overheard learning [Gitin 80a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=80&format=pdf), which was [slightly difficult to understand](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9702/5642), for one reason or another ;-)

Comment: In Chagiga 5b we find that they conversed in mime in front of the king. "?אמרו, גברא דלא ידע מאי מחוו ליה במחוג, יחוי קמי מלכא" and even killed a fellow for not being able to understand it. Doubt this answers your question.

Comment: I wrote an article about this which is due to be published in the coming weeks. I'll try to post a link when it is out.

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton Nice!!! That would be amazing! ....where is it going to be published?

Comment: My article has been printed here: http://seforim.blogspot.co.il/2014/12/abrahams-chaldean-origins-and-chaldee.html